# How can I call the "main" method using rJAVA?

Tags: javascript, r, rjava

I have a JAVA function like this in a .jar.

I want to call this function in R, but I am not being able to use the "main" method. Does anyone know how to call this "main" method using rJAVA to produce results?

I have read in a place that I need to create a separate static method in the JAVA code to access it, is that true?

```
public class CountJTrees
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Network<String,Object> g = Graphs.read();

            try
            {
                JTree<String> jjt = new JTree<String>(g);
                System.out.println(jjt.enumerate());
            }
            catch(GraphNotDecomposableException e)
            {
                System.out.println(0);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Caught CountJTrees.main()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have structure like this:

```
.
|-- Manifest.txt
`-- src
    `-- somepackage
        `-- StringTest.java
```

and file `StringTest.java` contains:

```
package somepackage;

public class StringTest {
  public String changeString(String str) {
    return "I have changed the string: " + str;
  }

  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    System.out.println(new StringTest().changeString("Hello"));
  }
}
```

You can easily build `JAR` file. With `Manifest.txt` file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: somepackage.StringTest
```

following way:

```
> jar cfm test.jar Manifest.txt -C target somepackage/StringTest.class

# execute JAR - just to test it works as expected
> java -jar test.jar
I have changed the string: Hello
```

Once your `JAR` is working as expected, you can run it in `R`

```
> export CLASSPATH=./test.jar
> R

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

...
...
...

> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
> obj <- .jnew("somepackage.StringTest")
> s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method="main", c("Hello", "Hello") )
I have changed the string: Hello
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I have the .jar already, I have "jtrees.jar" which has a CountJTrees.java file like this shown above when extracted. I am using the following code
`.jinit(.)`
`.jaddClassPath('jtrees.jar') `
`obj <- jnew("CountJTrees") `
`s <- jcall(countjtrees, "V", "main", "illustration")` 
I get error: 
`Error in .jcall(obj, "V", "main", c("Hello")) : method main with signature (Ljava/lang/String;)V not found`

Comment: You are passing `String` instead of array of `String`. You have to call it following way: `s <- jcall(countjtrees, "V", "main", c("illustration"))`

Comment: I tried it the same error happens.
`.jcall(obj,"V","main",c("illustration"))`
`Error in .jcall(obj, "V", "main", c("illustration")) : 
  method main with signature (Ljava/lang/String;)V not found`

Comment: Also relevant to this, I want to pass a filename as an argument. So, illustration is a filename which the function needs to read. Do I need to do anything special for that?

Comment: It's little bit strange, but it looks like `rJava` treats: `.jcall(obj, "V", "main", c("illustration"))` as a call with `String` argument while `.jcall(obj, "V", "main", c("illustration",""))` is treated as array. As a quick fix, simply pass: `c("illustration","")` and then, in your code, simply disregard last element of `String [] args`

Comment: I did that, it shows no error but R freezes and the code runs and runs making R unresponsive. So, I have to quit everytime without getting the result.

Comment: Well, I can't help you there ;( Looks like sort of code specific thing. If you try with simple `Hello world` sample, it works as expected.